# auxDIBImageLoad returns null

Tags: opengl, graphics

Hi i am doing a project with opengl

What I'm stuck with is that the method 'auxDIBImageLoad' always returns null even if the file exists.

My code is below:

```
AUX_RGBImageRec *LoadBMPFile(char *filename)
{
    FILE *hFile = NULL;
    if (!filename) return NULL;
    hFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (hFile)
    {
        printf("file opened\n");
        fclose(hFile);
        if (!auxDIBImageLoad(filename)) {
            printf("but file is null\n");
        }
        return auxDIBImageLoad( filename );
    }
    printf("file open failed\n");

    return NULL;
}
```

Then the log is below:

> file opened
>   but file is null
>   load bmp failed

I already searched for fixing it so that I already set to  **Multibyte char set**.

But it doesn't work after setting that.

Please help me.

Comment: What's your BMP file's exact format?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Is there any detail type of bmp file? My file is "blahblah.bmp"

Comment: @SurvivalMachine 512x256 pixel, 32bit-level, 226kb

Comment: Please stop using AUX. It was a terrible library when it was written *2 decades ago*, and age has not improved it. I'm not a big fan of SOIL, but it's infinitely superior to this.

Comment: @NicolBolas You mean that's because of the low performance of AUX?

Comment: @LKM: Because it is garbage in every way. It has a bad API. It hasn't been updated in over 20 years, so God only knows what bugs are there. You can't even fix any bugs you come across, since it's not open source. And so on. There is literally *no reason* to use it over a loader like SOIL.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for your detailed explanation. I think i need to search what you suggest, SOIL.